# Solution not found using search pattern 'd:\a\1\s\**\*.sln'

Tags: azure, github, azure-pipelines

I hope you are doing well.

Please excuse me by advance, I am new to this type of forum.

I have a problem deploying a build on Microsoft Azure Pipelines in the Microsoft Azures Pipelines set up phase.

My github repository is composed of main.py, requirements.txt and an Azure CI file.

Moreover, I am building with simple sample and not Python (Should I use Python?).

Here is my log:

```
##[section]Starting: Build solution
==============================================================================
Task         : Visual Studio build
Description  : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property
Version      : 1.151.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build
==============================================================================
##[error]Solution not found using search pattern 'd:\a\1\s\**\*.sln'.
##[section]Finishing: Build solution
```

Thank you by advance.

I am at your disposal should you have any question.

KR,

Ambroise

Comment: You try to build .net solution, do you have it in your repository?

Comment: Please navigate to Repos > Files to check if the solution file has been checked into the repository.You can refer to this case:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/540038/solution-not-found-error-occur-while-running-the-b.html

Answer (score 0):

May i know what project did you created? Is it a [python application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-01-create-project?view=vs-2019) project created by Visual Studio Template? As we know, Python automatically compiles your script to compiled code, so called byte code, before running it, there is no task in pipeline to build python. If you want to build a project by compiled language, such as C#, Java an so on, you need to add a build task for your project/solution.For example an ASP.NET project, the parameter `Path to project(s)` is necessary for the build task, it can a filter parten for a prject file(*.csproj) or a solution file(*.sln).